# Checking if the user is logged in or not using social authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, facebook-oauth

I have a method Where i save the user information after checking if the user is logged in or not :

```
 public function index()
    {
           if(Auth::check())
            {
                  $newuser=new User();
                  $newuser->username=Auth::user()->username;
                  $newuser->email=Auth::user()->email;
                  $newuser->save();
            }
            else 
            {
                 // not logged in
            }

    }
```

But, if the user is logged in using social authentication, `Auth::check()` shows false and else statement is executed. How can i check if the user is logged in using social authentication.Something like:

```
if(Auth::check() || Socialite::driver('facebook')->user())
{
   // logged in
}
else
{
   // not logged in
}
```

I can get the name and email with:

```
$username = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user()->username;
$email = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user()->email;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about you do `Auth::login($fbUser, true);` in the social authentication callback. Note `$fbUser` is the `Authenticatable` `user` model. You have to convert the social authentication user details into `user` model.

In this way `Auth::check()` and `Auth::user()` will return the FB user details.

Comment: But what if the user logged out from his social media account? How will you check that? Using this we can only check if the user is loggedin our website and not the providers website

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged in then you can get the user instance like this

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

so you function will be

```
public function index()
{
       $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
       if($user)
        {
              $newuser=new User();
              $newuser->username=$user->username;
              $newuser->email=$user->email;
              $newuser->save();
        }
        else
        {
             // not logged in
        }

}
```

so if the user is logged in using the social authentication then

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

will get that user instance for you 
and then you can save details of that user.

Comment: i want to not show not logged in if user is logged in using social authentication.

Comment: If the user is logged in using social authentication you can get that user instance by 
$user = $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
and then save username and email of that user into your database .